# I think my friend's steam account is hacked

Tags: steam

Almost all items on my friend's account were stolen about a week ago.

The strange thing is, that he has Steam Mobile Authenticator enabled but the "attack" somehow bypassed it. This happened once earlier, but we simply ignored it thinking that he has left his account logged-in somewhere, and changed his password immediately.

The trade history is empty and he didn't even get the "Trade Confirmation" notification on his phone.

I think he had tried to contact steam support earlier but no help.

Link to his profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/himanshu-Devilhunter

Link to post on steam forum: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/135509124600561789/

---

I have a few questions in this scenario:

1. How do we make sure that the account is protected and safe?
2. Is there any way that we can trace or know who is the *attacker*?
3. Is there any way that we can know where are those items, considering we have asset-id of all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we make sure that the account is protected and safe?

- Immediately change the password to a new, unique and strong one
- Change the password at least every 3 month, do not reuse an old password, always choose an unique and strong one
- consider to change the Email address of this account, and choose a new and unique password for the email account
- Remove the mobile authenticator and immediately set it up again, consider to change the phone number linked with your account
- Check if the devices used for this account are compromised (pc, notebook, smartphone etc.)

> Is there any way that we can trace or know who is the attacker?

Probably not, as far as I know. Maybe the support has access to this. But I think that's a dead end.

> Is there any way that we can know where are those items, considering we have asset-id of all of them?

If the trade history is empty only valve could know this, you can ask support, but I don't think it will work out.